# How can I spilt a row data in to below other rows

Tags: r

In below variable I want to divide 900000 in below its respective three rows where zero is present, similarly for other values. The number of zeroes to be counted dynamically before a new value arrives. `A_B` is data and `A_Bnew` is desired output. Please let me know how can I do it in R.

```
A_B    A_Bnew
0      0
0      0
900000 0
0      300000
0      300000
0      300000
10000  0
0      5000
0      5000
20000  0
0      5000
0      5000
0      5000
0      5000
0      0
0      0
0      0
```

The maximum number of zeroes it should consider to split is 4.

Comment: Why do you need this output?  What do you want to happen if a number in `A_B` does not zeroes below it?

Comment: Please add the expected output to your question to make it easier for us to understand and help you

Comment: The desired output is column name A_Bnew. I need the data in this manner to do analysis.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We can use `data.table`.  We convert the 'data.frame' to data.table' (`setDT(df1)`), create a grouping variable ('grp') by checking where 'A_B' is not equal to 0 to create a logical vector and getting the cumulative sum.  Grouped by 'grp', we set the 'i' where 'grp' is not equal to 0, create logical vector 'i1' where the 'A_B' is not 0.  Get the `sum` of 'i1', and use `pmin` to get the minimum value when compared with 4.   Then we subset the 'A_B' based on 'i1' and do an integer division with 'i2'.  We group by 'grp', get the row index ('.I`) based on the logical conditions and then assign the 'A_BnewNew' to 0.  If not needed, the 'grp' can be assigned to NULL.

```
library(data.table)
iN <- setDT(df1)[, grp := cumsum(A_B!=0)][grp!=0, A_BnewNew := {
           i1 <- A_B!=0; i2 <- pmin(sum(!i1),4)
           A_B[i1]%/%i2}  , by = grp
       ][, .I[!(A_B ==0 & grp !=0 & (1:.N) <= pmin(5, .N))]  , by = grp]$V1
 df1[iN, A_BnewNew:=0][, grp := NULL][]
#       A_B A_Bnew A_BnewNew
# 1:      0      0         0
# 2:      0      0         0
# 3: 900000      0         0
# 4:      0 300000    300000
# 5:      0 300000    300000
# 6:      0 300000    300000
# 7:  10000      0         0
# 8:      0   5000      5000
# 9:      0   5000      5000
#10:  20000      0         0
#11:      0   5000      5000
#12:      0   5000      5000
#13:      0   5000      5000
#14:      0   5000      5000
#15:      0      0         0
#16:      0      0         0
#17:      0      0         0
```

#### data

```
df1 <- structure(list(A_B = c(0L, 0L, 900000L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 10000L, 0L, 
 0L, 20000L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L), A_Bnew = c(0L, 0L, 0L, 
 300000L, 300000L, 300000L, 0L, 5000L, 5000L, 0L, 5000L, 5000L, 
 5000L, 5000L, 0L, 0L, 0L)), .Names = c("A_B", "A_Bnew"), 
 class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -17L))
```

Comment: hi...it seems to be working fine...can u pls also tell how to store A_BnewNew value in a vector or dataframe...as I have to loop in multiple variable...also pls provide short summary of above code to understand the flow and logic..

Comment: @user3974265  It is a data.table object.  So one way to extract the column is using `[[` ie.e. df1[["A_BnewNew"]]`.  If you want to convert to data.frame, use `setDF(df1)`

Comment: it is working fine...i will get back to you, if I face any issues in looping multiple variables...

Comment: @user3974265   Can you post it as a new question?