# How can I spilt a row data in to below other rows(with the logic mentioned below) using R

Tags: r

In below variable I want to divide each value in a certain criteria mentioned below:
A_B is the input data, A_Bnew is the required output. And below are some main points:

1. there is a lag of one data point in the output.
2. If there are two conitnuous non-zero values then it is pasted as it is.
3. If there are zeroes below any value then it should divide the number by the count of zeroes.
4. The maximum number of zeroes it should consider for division is 4.
5. The last two rows may or maynot be non-zero, since I will be looping multilple columns and here is just one sample.

   Below is sample output:

   ```
      A_B   A_Bnew
    25000        0
    20000    25000
   900000    20000
    25000   900000
        0    12500
        0    12500
    10000        0
        0     5000
        0     5000
    20000        0
        0     5000
        0     5000
        0     5000
        0     5000
        0        0
    12000        0
    12000    12000
   ```

thanks.

Comment: What about the condition with non-zero value at the end?  Does it have to be 2 continous non-zero?

Comment: I think you need to explain it better. Not clear what you want to do.

Comment: at the end it is dynamic, let's say i have 10 columns i have to perform this operation..in few columns last value may or may not be zero, since a lag is also happening so anyways last value will be out, the second last value need to be bring down...i hope you get it...if the last two values are zero then in o/p it  will be zero as well...please let me know, if any doubts..

Comment: I don't understand the first sentence gramatically. For example it is not clear what kind of " 900000" you are talking about. 900000 observations? Can you improve this?

Comment: in A_B is the input data, A_Bnew is required output. And below are some main points: 1) there is a lag of one data point in output. 2) If there are two conitnuous non-zero values then it is pasted as it is. 3) If there are zeroes below any value then it should divide the number by the count of zeroes. 4) The maximum number of zeroes it should consider for division is 4.

Comment: This may just me being dense. Can you elaborate on your question. What is the input and what is the expected output? Explain how you get from input to output in an algorithmic way if possible. Since akrun hasn't answered your question in minutes, I would say this is a good indicator of not a clear question. :)

Comment: please see the above response, do let me know if it is not clear..i will share more detailed one...

Comment: i have reframed the question, please refer to updated one

Comment: My (linguistical) hint to the updated question: "In below variable [I still would write 'In the variable below'] I want to divide ["divide" imo definitely wrong] each value [I would rephrase it like "I want to generate a new variable given the critera below"] in a certain criteria mentioned below: [...] 2. If there are two conitnuous [replace by "consecutive"] non-zero values then it is pasted as it is. [...]" A hint on formatting: keept the question as short as possible and replace `A_B` by `A` and `A_Bnew` by `B`.

Comment: How does this question differ from the [previous one](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38259506/how-can-i-spilt-a-row-data-in-to-below-other-rows)?

Comment: this question is different from previous one....although few things remain same...when the logic of a code is changed then the question is not necessarily the same..

Comment: @Cath But my code is not giving the output he wanted here.  So, it is not a dupe of my post

Comment: @akrun, which makes think that the first example was not representative of his real data. imo it doesn't deserve to be posted as another Q. Or, at least, the differences should be highlighted in the new Q because as it is, same title and same way of defining the Q makes it really hard to see a difference. Maybe you could edit, point to the previous Q and state the new constraints ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think I got it:

```
df$A_Bnew <- with(rle(df$A_B),{
    nz <- which(values!=0L);
    pre0 <- values[nz[-length(nz)]+1L]==0L;
    lens <- c(ifelse(pre0,lengths[nz+1L],1L),if (nz[length(nz)]<length(values)) lengths[length(lengths)] else 0L);
    mlens <- pmin(4L,lens);
    c(rep(0L,if (nz[1L]==1L) 1L else lengths[1L]+1L),rep(rbind(values[nz],values[nz]/mlens,0L),rbind(lengths[nz]-1L,mlens,lens-mlens+c(pre0,F))));
});
df;
##       A_B A_Bnew
## 1   25000      0
## 2   20000  25000
## 3  900000  20000
## 4   25000 900000
## 5       0  12500
## 6       0  12500
## 7   10000      0
## 8       0   5000
## 9       0   5000
## 10  20000      0
## 11      0   5000
## 12      0   5000
## 13      0   5000
## 14      0   5000
## 15      0      0
## 16  12000      0
## 17  12000  12000
```

**Data**

```
df <- data.frame(A_B=c(25000L,20000L,900000L,25000L,0L,0L,10000L,0L,0L,20000L,0L,0L,0L,0L,0L,
12000L,12000L));
```

---

## Explanation

```
nz <- which(values!=0L);
```

This computes the indexes of the non-zero run-lengths described by the `rle()` vector pair.

---

```
pre0 <- values[nz[-length(nz)]+1L]==0L;
```

We will need to know which of the non-zero run-lengths in the input were followed by run-lengths of zeroes. Hence we precompute this logical vector here.

The final non-zero run-length will have to be treated specially, so we must exclude it from this precomputation by indexing out the final element of `nz` before using it. Therefore, we must keep in mind that `pre0` is a logical vector corresponding to all but the final non-zero run-length in the input.

---

```
lens <- c(...,...);
```

This computes the total length over which each non-zero input value *could* be distributed in the output vector, if there was no limit on the distribution length.

We must separately compute the "general case", meaning the lengths for all but the final non-zero run-length, and the specific case of the final non-zero run-length. The general case is the first argument to the `c()` call, and the specific case is the second. I'll describe each of these separately below.

Note that, in the case of a repeated non-zero value, which will have been collapsed to a single run-length in the `rle()` vector pair, these lengths only describe how the *final* repetition of that non-zero value needs to be distributed in the output vector. The preceding repetitions are simpler and will be covered later on.

---

```
ifelse(pre0,lengths[nz+1L],1L)
```

The general case branches on the `pre0` test done earlier. In other words, it is branching on which of the non-zero run-lengths were followed by a run-length of zeroes in the input.

If true, the value returned is the length of that subsequent run-length of zeroes. This is correct because when followed by a run-length of zeroes, the preceding non-zero input value could be distributed over the entire run-length of zeroes, if there was no limit on the distribution length.

If false, the value returned is simply 1. This is correct because it must have been followed by a non-zero value in the input, which means there is only one row into which it can be distributed.

---

```
if (nz[length(nz)]<length(values)) lengths[length(lengths)] else 0L
```

The specific case covers the final non-zero run-length. We must test if it is the last or second-last run-length in the input. If second-last, its output length will be the entire final run-length of zeroes which necessarily followed it in the input. If last, we can simply return a length of zero, because the final repetition of the final non-zero value disappears from the output vector.

---

```
mlens <- pmin(4L,lens);
```

Now we must compute a modification on the `lens` vector which applies the distribution length limit. We can use `pmin()` for this purpose.

Note that we must not overwrite `lens` because it will be needed later on. Hence we assign it to a new variable, `mlens`.

---

```
c(...,...)
```

The final statement in the braced block computes the required output vector. We must combine two pieces: (1) a segment of one or more zeroes, which is required due to the nature of the task (i.e. lagging the input vector, among other things), and (2) the remainder. I'll describe each of these separately below.

---

```
rep(0L,if (nz[1L]==1L) 1L else lengths[1L]+1L)
```

In the case that the first non-zero run-length was in fact the first run-length in the input vector, we only need 1 leading zero in the output vector. Otherwise, the first run-length had to have been a run-length of zeroes, and therefore we need as many leading zeroes as there were in that run-length, plus 1 for the subsequent row.

---

```
rep(rbind(...,...,...),rbind(...,...,...))
```

The final piece of code derives a base vector of triplets and a parallel vector of repetition counts to pass to `rep()`. Each base vector element will be repeated by the corresponding count in the repetition vector. We can use `rbind()` to build both vectors as a sequence of triplets. This works because of how matrices are naturally laid out in memory; *across* rows (IOW *along* columns) first-and-foremost, and only then *across* columns (*along* rows).

I'll cover each member of the triplets below in the order they occur in the `rbind()` calls, giving both base vector and repetition vector intermittences.

---

```
values[nz]
lengths[nz]-1L
```

The first piece covers the case of repeated non-zero values in the input. For each repetition *prior* to the final repetition of the non-zero value, we must instantiate a single corresponding element in the output vector, whose value will be equal to the input non-zero value, as it is not distributed over more than 1 row. Hence the value is passed verbatim, and the length is 1 less than the length of the input run-length.

---

```
values[nz]/mlens
mlens
```

The second piece covers the distribution of the (final repetition of the) non-zero value over its subsequent rows, up to the distribution length limit. We already precomputed the capped distribution lengths as `mlens`, hence we can use that directly as the repetition count. The value is the non-zero value divided by the number of rows over which it will be distributed, IOW divided by `mlens`.

---

```
0L
lens-mlens+c(pre0,F)
```

The final piece is a segment of zeroes which actually satisfies two requirements.

First, in the cases where `mlens` is smaller than `lens`, IOW where the distribution length was actually capped by the limit, we must supplement the distribution of the non-zero value with one or more zeroes to cover the shortfall. The number of zeroes required here is obviously just `lens-mlens`.

Second, in the case that a non-zero run-length was followed by a run-length of zeroes, we must instantiate a single zero to complete the lag of the run-length of zeroes into the subsequent row. We can simply add `pre0` to do this, since logical vectors coerce to 1 for true and 0 for false. But, because `pre0` is short by 1 due to its exclusion of the final non-zero run-length, we must supplement it with a single element to cover that final run-length. This element must be false, since the run-length of zeroes that may follow the final non-zero run-length cannot itself be followed by a row into which it can lag a zero.

Comment: hi, can you please provide a small explanation to above code logic and flow...i am trying to verify it on complete dataset..

Comment: yes you are right....it is working